# Is Oraclize / Provable Things dying?

Tags: oracles, randomness

I'm doing some research on how to generate truly random numbers on the blockchain.
Aside from Chainlink VRF, the other viable solution seems to be Provable Things (former Oraclize) with their random oracle. Even though it may raise questions on true decentralization for the randomness generation, it is much more convenient since it takes ETH instead of LINK to pay fees.

All good, the only problem is that everything I found online indicates that the project was quite active a couple of years ago but now it seems slow and even somewhat broken on some pages. Their documentation here (http://docs.provable.xyz/#pricing-advanced-datasources-testnets-policy) had its last update in 2019, while the query tester here (https://app.provable.xyz/) seems to be broken for some tests (computation) and also testing for random is missing.

Is the project dying or somewhat abandoned or pivoting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit an off-topic question, but the best way to check whether a company is still *alive* is by looking at the official registry.

In this case, you can find it [here](https://find-and-update.company-information.service.gov.uk/company/10334939). The company is active, but you will have the certainty by May'21, where they have to submit the accounts.

However, the fact that a company is legally active doesn't mean their product/s are live and supported. I did a quick check on their repos, website, etc and as you pointed out, changes in code are quite old, activity in social media is almost gone and when clicking at the [protocol status](https://status.provable.xyz/), the SSL certificate is expired since Jan21.

Therefore, unless you contact them directly to double-check, I would look for other alternatives in case you need an Oracle.

Comment: Yes, this was more of a "community question" rather than a technical question. Thanks for the response.